# "connection refused" error in main application until istio-sidecar starts

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have problem with start order of istio-sidecar and main application in kubernetes.
When pod starts, main application getting error "connection refused" for external services. When istio-envoy proxy ready, main application starts correctly on next attempt.

While Istio is not ready, the main application has time to crash and restart 2-3 times

how do I make the main application wait for istio-sidecar to start and only then start running itself?

Comment: Well known [issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/11130).

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you set holdApplicationUntilProxyStarts to true will solve your issue.
You can get more information about it here:
https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/injection/
Hope it can help you.